# Remove similar elements from 2 vectors (or list) not using <algorithm>

Tags: c++, list, vector, stl

I want to remove similar elements from 2 vectors (or list) . I found [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641724/remove-the-common-entities-from-two-vector), he used `<algorimth>` to solve the problem. **My question is** is the any other approaches without using `<algorimth>`?

Mine is I create a vector to save the indices of the common elements, then delete the elements have the 'tagged' index. Wild idea though, this ain't work.

An example :

```
Vector A={1,2,3,4,5};
Vector B={2,3,4,6};
Vector result={1,5};
```

Comment: I mean we do it without     `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: Are the values always sorted, or could you have `A = { 3, 1, 5, 9, 4 }`?

Comment: Also, are all the values unique, or could you have `A = {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, ... }`?

Comment: Let's say all the values are unique and sorted.

Comment: My question: Why are you not looking into the std::algorithm and try to adopt it for your special purpose (if there is one) ?

Comment: Hi, it's pure curiosity :)

Comment: Isn't this just a straightforward merge (with a test to ignore equal values)? Maybe you really need to read a book on algorithms. I would recommend Udi Manber's.

Comment: No and yes :)  I want a function take 2 vector and return a "offset" vector between those two :) The answer of Mats Petersson included it so it's okay for me. You're right about my skill, I'm pretty weak and working on it. Thank for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case where all values are unique and sorted, the following would work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> A={1,2,3,4,5};
vector<int> B={2,3,4,6};
vector<int> result;


int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    while(a < A.size() && b < B.size())
    {
        /* Same value - skip to next on both sides */
        if (A[a] == B[b])
        {
            a++;
            b++;
        }
        else 
            /* Smaller value is unique, so push back that */
            if (A[a] < B[b])
            {
                result.push_back(A[a]);
                a++;
            }
            else
            {
                result.push_back(B[b]);
                b++;
            }
    } 

    while (a < A.size())
    { 
        result.push_back(A[a]);
        a++;
    }
    while (b < B.size())
    { 
        result.push_back(B[b]);
        b++;
    }

    for(auto r : result)
    {
        cout << r << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

There are a number of other methods. If the values aren't enormous, one could use an array to count up when you encounter the value in A, then count down for B, and then go through the array of counters when finished to give a list of unique values.

Edit: Updated with complete code that "works".

Comment: Can you say something more about your 2nd and 3rd `while` loop? I don't really understand :(

Comment: The second and third while-loop takes care of "whatever is left" from the main while-loop - for example in your case the `6` in the `B` (which is also missing from the `result`, I believe).

Comment: I tried your code,the 2nd and the 3rd seem have a problem, they don't work as you intend :( However I get the idea :)

Comment: I have updated with a complete program, which works for the test-case given, outputting 1,5,6.

Comment: What did you change? It looks like you just add the loop to display the `result`? And It does work !

Comment: So, there was a semicolon on the first while-loop that shouldn't have been there (a result of changing from a `do - while` to `while`.

Comment: Ah, I got it, thank! I need to do much to improve my skill :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with lists that already takes care to SORT and UNIQUE the input.

```
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int A_arrey[] = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8 };
    int B_arrey[] = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
    list<int> A_list(A_arrey, A_arrey + 6);
    list<int> B_list(B_arrey, B_arrey + 7);
    A_list.sort();
    A_list.unique();
    B_list.sort();
    B_list.unique();

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(A_arrey) / sizeof(A_arrey[0]); i++)
        B_list.remove(A_arrey[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(B_arrey) / sizeof(B_arrey[0]); i++)
        A_list.remove(B_arrey[i]);

    A_list.merge(B_list);

    cout << "My list contains:";
    for (list<int>::iterator it = A_list.begin(); it != A_list.end(); it++)
        std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    cout << '\n';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

```
vector<T> v(SIZE);
T tmp=v[0];
// ... Fill your vector here

for(int i=0;i<SIZE;++i)
    v[i]==tmp?v.erase(i):tmp=v[i];
```

Comment: Plain wrong silly code (would love to down-vote the brainless up-voter)